# Magento remove products custom options

Tags: php, magento

Hi I need to be able to remove a product custom options programatically.

I have made this function:

```
public function removeOptions($option_name, $product_id) {

$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id); 
$options = $product->getOptions();
  foreach($options as $option) {

if(strtolower($option->getTitle()) == $option_name) {
    unset($product->getOptions());
    }

  }

}
```

But I am getting this error 'Can't use method return value in write context'

What do I need to change  unset($product->getOptions()); to?

Jason

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The general issue is in code syntax - the `unset($product->getOptions());` says to PHP to unlink the name (variable, array index or object property) from the value it stores. However, entity that is returned by the method/function call, has no name. I.e. it is not a variable, object property or array index, it is just a pure value. So calling `unset()` on it doesn't make sense.

It is not a Magento error, it is violation of general PHP syntax.

If you want to unset options in a Product model, then you need to go other way. First of all, you need to change syntax. Second, you need to note that Product model is not designed to change custom options dynamically.

You have two options, how to implement desired functionality:

1) If you need just to delete option and save product, then you need to change `unset($product->getOptions());` to

```
$optionsData = $option->getData();
$optionsData['is_delete'] = 1;

$product->setProductOptions(array($option->getId() => $optionsData));
$product->setCanSaveCustomOptions(true);
$product->save();
```

Loading product again will return you the product without the option:

```
$product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($product_id);
```

2) If you need to delete option and continue working with the same Product model, then you need to rewrite Product model class ([this article](http://magedev.com/2009/06/03/magento-overriding-model-block-or-helper/) explains how to do that) and add your custom method to unset the property you want. That is how a rewrited class would look like:

```
class MageDev_NewCatalog_Model_Product extends Mage_Catalog_Model_Product {
    public function unsetOption($optionId) {
        unset($this->_options[$optionId];
    }
}
```

Then you need to change `unset($product->getOptions());` to `$product->unsetOption($option->getId())`.

Comment: Cheers Andrey, I went with the first option and it worked perfectly. Thank you as well for taking the time to explain what I was doing wrong. That was a big help